# Export large list to excel through powershell

Tags: list, powershell

We can successfully migrate a list to the excel through power-shell, but if a list is having 1 Lakh of data then can we transfer through power-shell? Is there any restriction on number of list items for this type of transfer?

Answer (score 2):

As one of the above comments mentions [Kirk Evans has nice articel explaining that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2012/02/13/iterating-large-sharepoint-lists-with-powershell/).

Basically you would not list all items using `(Get-SPWeb http://foo.bar/).Lists["ListName"].Items` - this will most likely error because of the [threshold](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/demystifying-the-sharepoint-lists-thresholds).

You would create a query (`New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery`) which can be limited to a sensible number of items (`$spQuery.RowLimit = 2000` in the article above) and then run that query against the list (`Get-SPWeb http://foo.bar/).Lists["ListName"].GetItems($spQuery)`).

When the query is run the result will have a property `ListItemCollectionPosition`. If that is `$null` the `RowLimit` has not been reached and you have all the items you queried for. If the `ListItemCollectionPosition` is not null you can use that on the query as a new "starting-point" for the next query (`$spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition`) - run the query again and you'll get the next batch of items.

So, to "copy" Kirk Evans freely:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://portal.sharepoint.com
$list = $web.Lists["LargeList"]

$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
$spQuery.RowLimit = 2000
$caml = '<OrderBy Override="TRUE"><FieldRef Name="ID"/></OrderBy>' 
$spQuery.Query = $caml 

do {
    $listItems = $list.GetItems($spQuery)
    $spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    $listItems | % {
        Write-Output [pscustomobject]@{
            ID=$_.ID; 
            Title=$_.Title;
            WhatEverField=$_["someCoolField"];
        }
    }
} while ($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```

The result of the above will be a list of objects (note, that [you'll need PowerShell v3 for the `[pscustomobject@{...}]`-feature](http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2011/09/powershell-v3-creating-objects-with-pscustomobject-its-fast.html)), wich can be nicely piped to [`Export-CSV`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) or even [`Out-GridView`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849920.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$MyWeb = WebUrl 
$MyList = MyWeb.Lists["ListName"] 
$MyItems = $MyList.Items 
$MyItems | Select Fields.. | Export-Csv
FilePath
$MyWeb.Dispose()
```

Sources:

- [Export SharePoint List to Excel using PowerShell.](http://iwillsharemypoint.blogspot.com/2011/02/export-sharepoint-2010-list-to-excel.html)
- [Export sharepoint list items to csv using powershell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/export-sharepoint-list-items-to-csv-using-powershell.html)

Comment: Is there any restriction on number of list items for this type of transfer?

Comment: The same limits as SharePoint enforces. Try that technique along with [Kirk Evans'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/02/13/iterating-large-sharepoint-lists-with-powershell.aspx) - PS:Learned a new word... Lakh

Comment: 1 Lakh means 100,000 number

Comment: If your list contains 100000 items I would urge you to rethink that. Usually lists have a 5000 item threshold, going over that can severely impact performance,